# Using the date of a result column as a partial input

Tags: mysql

I have the current database

```
ID(int) | DateTime(Time Stamp) | Date 

  1       2017-02-17 09:01:00     2017-02-17
  2       2017-02-17 09:40:00     2017-02-17
  3       2017-02-17 10:01:00     2017-02-17
  4       2017-02-18 09:01:00     2017-02-18
```

I want a report of how many entries happened within the hour.

as the result would look something similar to this

```
 9 (occurances) | 10 | Date
      2           1     2017-02-17
      1           0     2017-02-18
```

The time should be a 1-hour range for example `9-10 10-11 11-12`, i'm not limiting this to the mentioned hours and i wouldn't mind having all 24 time enteries `00-23` mentioned with a lot of 0 counts

ETA:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`t1` (
  `ID` INT(8) NOT NULL,
  `DateTime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
( 1,'2016-09-21 08:17:06'),( 2,'2016-09-21 05:41:52'),( 3,'2016-09-21 16:34:26'),
( 4,'2016-09-21 23:44:20'),( 5,'2016-09-21 03:32:18'),( 6,'2016-09-21 07:07:24'),
( 7,'2016-09-21 18:23:59'),( 8,'2016-09-21 22:03:26'),( 9,'2016-09-21 20:36:59'),
(10,'2016-09-21 00:47:22'),(11,'2016-09-21 18:53:45'),(12,'2016-09-21 00:32:56'),
(13,'2016-09-21 09:57:49'),(14,'2016-09-21 23:04:26'),(15,'2016-09-21 12:34:50'),
(16,'2016-09-21 12:52:50'),(17,'2016-09-21 18:12:25'),(18,'2016-09-21 15:36:35'),
(19,'2016-09-21 03:34:14'),(20,'2016-09-21 12:44:27'),(21,'2016-09-21 08:46:10'),
(22,'2016-09-21 11:57:01'),(23,'2016-09-21 18:27:12'),(24,'2016-09-21 20:54:15'),
(25,'2016-09-21 07:50:16'),(26,'2016-09-21 10:26:17'),(27,'2016-09-21 20:26:18'),
(28,'2016-09-21 07:19:25'),(29,'2016-09-21 17:08:32'),(30,'2016-09-21 13:17:43'),
(31,'2016-09-21 21:48:19'),(32,'2016-09-21 07:41:26'),(33,'2016-09-21 18:12:33'),
(34,'2016-09-21 04:09:05'),(35,'2016-09-21 02:21:05'),(36,'2016-09-21 16:16:26'),
(37,'2016-09-21 15:26:51'),(38,'2016-09-21 02:37:31'),(39,'2016-09-21 02:00:44'),
(40,'2016-09-21 11:40:07'),(41,'2016-09-21 03:00:36'),(42,'2016-09-21 09:37:10'),
(43,'2016-09-21 10:52:06'),(44,'2016-09-21 10:27:09'),(45,'2016-09-21 08:36:48'),
(46,'2016-09-21 11:57:46'),(47,'2016-09-21 17:37:59'),(48,'2016-09-21 08:40:01'),
(49,'2016-09-21 04:32:37'),(50,'2016-09-21 04:08:12'),(51,'2016-09-21 23:57:52'),
(52,'2016-09-21 15:21:58'),(53,'2016-09-21 04:26:47'),(54,'2016-09-21 07:06:01'),
(55,'2016-09-21 15:34:33'),(56,'2016-09-21 10:57:48'),(57,'2016-09-21 01:06:47'),
(58,'2016-09-21 01:36:12'),(59,'2016-09-21 08:25:12'),(60,'2016-09-21 14:21:54'),
(61,'2016-09-21 22:33:56'),(62,'2016-09-21 12:40:25'),(63,'2016-09-21 12:56:53'),
(64,'2016-09-21 23:24:07'),(65,'2016-09-21 07:00:37'),(66,'2016-09-21 20:50:22'),
(67,'2016-09-21 04:38:22'),(68,'2016-09-21 07:13:37'),(69,'2016-09-21 13:39:03'),
(70,'2016-09-21 12:40:27'),(71,'2016-09-21 01:10:00'),(72,'2016-09-21 13:22:29'),
(73,'2016-09-21 10:21:02'),(74,'2016-09-21 15:50:50'),(75,'2016-09-21 05:29:15'),
(76,'2016-09-21 16:12:18'),(77,'2016-09-21 01:29:04'),(78,'2016-09-21 18:20:24'),
(79,'2016-09-21 23:06:50'),(80,'2016-09-21 23:27:11'),(81,'2016-09-21 13:09:08'),
(82,'2016-09-21 01:01:15'),(83,'2016-09-21 05:18:50'),(84,'2016-09-21 21:28:20'),
(85,'2016-09-21 11:47:06'),(86,'2016-09-21 03:25:06'),(87,'2016-09-21 08:05:07'),
(88,'2016-09-21 09:11:52'),(89,'2016-09-21 19:56:53'),(90,'2016-09-21 19:13:29'),
(91,'2016-09-21 02:40:38'),(92,'2016-09-21 19:31:36'),(93,'2016-09-21 14:06:02'),
(94,'2016-09-21 14:35:31'),(95,'2016-09-21 03:59:12'),(96,'2016-09-21 08:10:15'),
(97,'2016-09-21 09:52:13'),(98,'2016-09-21 15:21:01'),(99,'2016-09-21 00:21:38');
```

Suggested query to get started:

```
SELECT aa.DateTime, DATE(aa.DateTime) AS YYYY_MM_DD, 
       TIME(aa.DateTime) AS HH_MM_SS, 
       FLOOR(TIME(aa.DateTime)/10000) AS HourOfDay, 
       t2.nbr AS 'Count Per Hour'  
FROM   (t1 aa INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT t1.DateTime, COUNT(t1.DateTime) as nbr 
        FROM  t1 GROUP BY FLOOR(TIME(t1.DateTime)/10000)) AS t2 ON 
       FLOOR(TIME(aa.DateTime)/10000) = FLOOR(TIME(t2.DateTime)/10000))
ORDER BY YYYY_MM_DD ASC, HH_MM_SS DESC;
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ It's a MySQL server

Answer (score 0):

Throw more detail and more sample data.

you cannot pull all the data.you have to pull data of some specific date which you pass as parameter.

```
here consider @DateTable  is parameter.or you pass detail what you want
```

you can try some thing like this,

```
declare @DateTable table(ReportDate datetime)
insert into @DateTable values('2017-06-02'),('2017-06-03')

create table #t (colTime datetime)
insert into #t 
select  dateadd(hour,number,ReportDate)  from @DateTable
cross apply(select distinct number  from master..spt_values where number>0 and number<25
)ca

--select * from #t

--analyze this
--select *
--from #t t
--left join table1 v
--on t.colTime=dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, v.ModifiedDate), 0) 


select t.colTime  
,count(id)
from #t t
left join table1 v
on t.colTime=dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, v.ModifiedDate), 0) 
group by t.colTime

drop table #t
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's Microsoft SQL Server and if I haven't made mistakes then this formula,

```
CASE WHEN ( DATEPART(hour, [datetime]) = 9 ) THEN 1 END
AS NINE_AM
```

will evaluate as 1 for time 9am-10am and NULL otherwise.  Then you can SUM or COUNT it - I think COUNT(NINE_AM) may be quicker which is why I left it as 1 or NULL; NULL doesn't contribute to COUNT.  If "ANSI warnings" bother you, then change it to SUM and to  ... 1 ELSE 0 END.

But the other ways may be better.

Actually you'd need to use the formula inside SUM or COUNT and not a column name, although you could do,

```
SELECT COUNT(wtmh.NINE_AM) AS Count_9AM, wtmh.Date
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
          CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, [datetime]) = 9 ) THEN 1 END
          AS NINE_AM
        , 
          Date
    FROM 
    table
    )
    AS wtmh /* where the magic happens */
GROUP BY wtmh.Date 
ORDER BY wtmh.Date
```

### Update

For MySQL, which I don't know - glancing at documentation online, HOUR() is equivalent to Microsoft's DATEPART() but I don't know if HOUR() works on a "timestamp".  If it doesn't then LEFT(TIME(datetime), 2) should get out the hours part of time - but then what?  Well - if this is right -

```
LOCATE('09', LEFT(TIME(datetime), 2))
```

should evaluate to 1 if the time is '09' - 9am - and to 0 otherwise?  But may be not the best way to do it.  If it works, duplicate the formula for 10am, 11am, etc.

Comment: It's actually a MySQL server

Comment: @Newbie I updated my answer, maybe another formula will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want a Pivot the query would be pretty simple but return the wanted results in different layout, one row per date and hour:

```
SELECT date(datetime) AS date, hour(datetime) AS hour
FROM test.t1
GROUP BY date(datetime), hour(datetime) ;
```

The pivot can be done with various ways. Here's one:

```
SELECT
    date(datetime) AS date,
    SUM(hour(datetime) =  0) AS hour00,
    SUM(hour(datetime) =  1) AS hour01,
    SUM(hour(datetime) =  2) AS hour02,
    -- 
    --
    SUM(hour(datetime) = 22) AS hour22,
    SUM(hour(datetime) = 23) AS hour23
FROM test.t1
GROUP BY date(datetime) ;
```

Test in **[dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=afe8c721feb05f0fee9e6ce7ef29491b)**.